# Transfer data to redis using R // redux

Tags: r, dataframe, redis, redux

I have read a `.CSV` file in R using the `read.csv()` command. I have established a connection to Redis and now I need to transfer the dataframe as-is (`csv` content that I loaded in R) to redis.

I'm using the `r$HMSET()` to multi-set values, but this means that I enter all the data of each entry manually by myself.

Is there a command that automatically transfers all the data?

*Most sources I was able to find uses Python or rredis package so it is not very helpful to me since I have to use R and redux.*

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I used the `r$RPUSH` command within a `for` loop (running for the length of my `.csv` file).